# Don't understand how work logical operator works

Tags: c#, logical-operators

how its work?? -

```
 Debug.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}",(dy == 0), (dx == 0),((dy == 0)&&(dy == 0)));
```

output:

> true, false, **true**

how is this possible?

Comment: _"The computer says **no**"_ - it is correct.  Did you by chance mean `((dx == 0)&&(dy == 0))`?

Comment: you have typo i guess. you put `dy` twice.`(***dy == 0)&&(***dy == 0)`

Comment: Ohhhh thenks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
((dy == 0)&&(dy == 0))
```

You're checking if the same variable is equal to 0 twice, the same variable you have already established is equal to zero before.

`((dy == 0)&&(dx == 0))` will return false since one expression evaluates to `true` and the other to `false` so joining them with `&&` which is an `AND` boolean operator will result in `false`.

Comment: my output: true, false, true , ((dy == 0)&&(dx == 0)) - return TRUE

Comment: @user3425924 _"((dy == 0)&&(dx == 0)) - return TRUE"_ - That's **not** what is stated in your question

Comment: sorry this my first question in this site...
I dont unerstand how work logical operator and in my code! 
after code i write line output
"output: true, false, true - how is this possible?"

Comment: Debug.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}",(dy == 0), (dx == 0),((dy == 0)&&(dy == 0))); - in this code! ) mey be I do not use right &&

Comment: @user3425924 if you meant to say `((dy == 0)&&(dx == 0))` you should edit your question to reflect that, which changes the answer. As it stands, you either have a typo or you have a basic misunderstanding of boolean logic.

Answer (score 1):

If `(dy == 0) = true`,

`(dy == 0)&&(dy == 0)` will also be true, of course.